# How to improve JavaFX chart performance?

Tags: performance, charts, javafx-8

I want to visualize a static chart with 10 series each having 10'000 points using JavaFX.
After my first tests I'm a bit worried about the performance of the JavaFX chart API, especially about the constructor `new XYChart.Series<>(...)` which takes 3 minutes of initialization for 100'000 data points.

If you don't believe me, run the code below:

```
public static final int SIZE = 100000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>> data = new ArrayList<>(SIZE);

    measureTime("creating list", () -> {
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
            data.add(new XYChart.Data<>(i, i));
        }
    });

    measureTime("creating series", () -> {
        new XYChart.Series<>(FXCollections.observableList(data));
    });
}

public static void measureTime(String msg, Runnable f) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    f.run();
    long end = System.nanoTime();

    System.err.println("Time for " + msg + ": " + (end - start) / 1000000 + " ms");
}
```

These are the results on my computer:

```
Time for creating list: 62 ms
Time for creating series: 173555 ms
```

Why does this initialization take so long and how can one work around this?

Or is there a way to use the JavaFX charts without Observables?

Comment: hmmm ... can't reproduce: my output is about 400 ms/150 ms (jdk8u40b23, that is a recent ea before the current release)

Comment: Your right. This bug was seemingly fixed with Java 8u40.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like series creation was a performance issue which was fixed between Java 8u25 and Java 8u40.

I ran your application on 8u25 and got the following result:

```
Time for creating list: 59 ms 
Time for creating series: 135896 ms
```

Upgrading to 8u40 and running again, I got the following result:

```
Time for creating list: 66 ms
Time for creating series: 80 ms
```

So, just update to the [latest Java version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So far I used only Java 8u20 and 8u31 which had these performance problems. Didn't even know that 8u40 is already available. I tested it now with 8u40 and it works like a charm.

Comment: Anyway, the loading performance and especially the drawing performance of the JavaFX charts are even with Java 8 update 66 dramatically bad compared to JFreeChart. When it comes to frequent updates of charts then don't use JavaFX charts!

Comment: @Stefan I wonder if the JavaFX chart performance issues you are seeing for frequent updates might be improved if [animation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#setAnimated-boolean-) is switched off for the chart.  Still, there will be some chart types for which JFreeChart will be more appropriate.  When you use JFreeChart, have you tried it via the [FXGraphics2D bridge](http://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/), so that it JFreeChart directly renders to a JavaFX canvas, and, if so, does that perform OK for your scenarios?

Comment: @jewelsea What types of charts are more performantly rendered with JFreeChart and FXGraphics2D bridge.  I'm finding I can only render about 1000 - 1500 points per second with a JavaFX LineChart on a quad core RPi,  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943662/linechart-javafx-performance), with animation off, and am looking for a faster solution.

Comment: I don't know, you would need to benchmark the particular charts you are interested in yourself.